# How to calculate vector magnitude with a constant?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

In a case where we have an operation in which we have constants in the vector length by default, how can we calculate it?

e.g.
$$
\lVert c_1 \cdot v\rVert^2 = c_1\cdot\lVert v\rVert^2 \\
\text{or } \\\lVert c_1 \cdot v\rVert^2 = c_1^2\cdot\lVert v\rVert^2
$$

I know the question is very basic but I did not find on the forum an answer to this property.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lVert c_1 \cdot v\rVert= |c_1|\cdot\lVert v\rVert$, so $\lVert c_1 \cdot v\rVert^2 = c_1^2\cdot\lVert v\rVert^2$.

Answer (score 0):

The latter. Note that you want the result to be positive, even if $c_1$ is negative so the first does not work.